# Tab function not working in firefox using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

here is the code:

```js
$(".onlynumbers").keydown(function(e) {
  var isModifierkeyPressed = (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey);
  var isCursorMoveOrDeleteAction = ([46, 8, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1);
  var isNumKeyPressed = (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 58) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105);
  var vKey = 86,
    cKey = 67,
    aKey = 65;
  switch (true) {
    case isCursorMoveOrDeleteAction:
    case isModifierkeyPressed == false && isNumKeyPressed:
    case (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && ([vKey, cKey, aKey].indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1):
      break;
    default:
      e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="enterCheckCheckNumber" maxlength="12" style="width:70%; float: right;" type="text" class="form-controlEnterCheck onlynumbers" placeholder="Check Number" />
```

Comment: Thats because you are stopping the event if not number and Tab is not a number

Comment: It's working in FF for me, have you looked at the developer tools, if there are any other errors?

Comment: @martinczerwi in my firefox , tab functionality is not working but copy paste and only number in input are working.

Comment: @martinczerwi no error found in developer tool

Answer (score 0):

As commented before, the issue is you are stopping event if its not in mentioned keys. You will have to either add special keys like `Tabs`, `Delete`, `Caps` etc or you can just allow user to enter anything and then you clean it once typed.

```js
$(".onlynumbers").on("input",function(e) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="enterCheckCheckNumber" maxlength="12" style="width:70%; float: right;" type="text" class="form-controlEnterCheck onlynumbers" placeholder="Check Number" />
```

Comment: its taking alphabet also and i want to enable copy paste tab and only number functionality

Comment: it is taking alp[habets also

Comment: I'm sorry but can you share the test case? I have tried `typing` and `pasting` and it is not accepting anything but number

Answer (score 0):

var key = 'which' in e ? e.which : e.keyCode;

Try using this piece of code.

```
$(".onlynumbers").keydown(function(e) {
  var isModifierkeyPressed = (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey);
  var isCursorMoveOrDeleteAction = ([46, 8, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1);
  var isNumKeyPressed = (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 58) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105);
  var vKey = 86,
    cKey = 67,
    aKey = 65,
   keycode = event.which;
  switch (true) {
    case isCursorMoveOrDeleteAction:
    case isModifierkeyPressed == false && isNumKeyPressed:
    case (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && ([vKey, cKey, aKey, keycode].indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1):
      break;
    default:
      e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Change the input type to number in html.

Comment: the code is working but taking the alphabets also @skelly santhu